# Angular - global infos: static class VS service

Tags: angular

I have a requirement for a class with global constant and static information and functions.

E.g.

```
export class Globals
{
  public static version : string = "v2.2";

  public static rest_service : string = "http://somewhere";

  public static debug (msg : string) : void
  {
    console.log (msg);
  }
}
```

Is it better design in Angular if I do that with a static class where I use the class-members

OR

with an injected service that is only provided in the top-module and use object-members??

Comment: the best is to use a service as it will use Angulars DI